# Emulating boolean masks in Theano

Tags: numpy, theano

I'm porting a numpy expression to theano.  The expression finds the number of true positive predictions for each class, given a one-hot matrix `Y` of ground truth classes and a one-hot matrix `Y_hat` of predicted classes.  The numpy code is:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 2, 2])
y_hat = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1, 0])

Y = np.zeros(shape=(len(y), len(np.unique(y))))
Y_hat = np.zeros_like(Y)

rows = np.arange(len(y))

Y[rows, y] = 1
Y_hat[rows, y_hat] = 1

((Y_hat == Y) & (Y == 1)).sum(axis=0)
```

The last expression yields `array([1, 1, 0])`.  I've tried using theano's nonzero:

```
from theano import shared
Yt = shared(Y)
Yt_hat = shared(Y_hat)
Yt_hat[Yt.nonzero()].eval()
```

The eval results in `array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.])`, which is a 0-1 mask of the rows of `Yt_hat` where the prediction is correct.  Any suggestions for how to make this work?  For different ways of doing it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three variants demonstrating how to re-implement parts of your numpy code in Theano.

Note that Theano's `Unique` operation does not support running on the GPU and does not appear to support gradients either. As a result version 3 many not be of much use. Version 2 provides a workaround: compute the unique values outside Theano and pass them in. Version 1 is a Theano implementation of the final line of your numpy code only.

To address your specific issue: there is no need to use `nonzero`; in this case the indexing works in Theano just like it works in numpy. Maybe you were getting confused between `y` and `Y`? (common Python style is to stick with lower case for all variable and parameter names).

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.tensor.extra_ops


def numpy_ver(y, y_hat):
    Y = np.zeros(shape=(len(y), len(np.unique(y))), dtype=np.int64)
    Y_hat = np.zeros_like(Y, dtype=np.int64)
    rows = np.arange(len(y), dtype=np.int64)
    Y[rows, y] = 1
    Y_hat[rows, y_hat] = 1
    return ((Y_hat == Y) & (Y == 1)).sum(axis=0), Y, Y_hat


def compile_theano_ver1():
    Y = tt.matrix(dtype='int64')
    Y_hat = tt.matrix(dtype='int64')
    z = (tt.eq(Y_hat, Y) & tt.eq(Y, 1)).sum(axis=0)
    return theano.function([Y, Y_hat], outputs=z)


def compile_theano_ver2():
    y = tt.vector(dtype='int64')
    y_hat = tt.vector(dtype='int64')
    y_uniq = tt.vector(dtype='int64')
    Y = tt.zeros(shape=(y.shape[0], y_uniq.shape[0]), dtype='int64')
    Y_hat = tt.zeros_like(Y, dtype='int64')
    rows = tt.arange(y.shape[0], dtype='int64')
    Y = tt.set_subtensor(Y[rows, y], 1)
    Y_hat = tt.set_subtensor(Y_hat[rows, y_hat], 1)
    z = (tt.eq(Y_hat, Y) & tt.eq(Y, 1)).sum(axis=0)
    return theano.function([y, y_hat, y_uniq], outputs=z)


def compile_theano_ver3():
    y = tt.vector(dtype='int64')
    y_hat = tt.vector(dtype='int64')
    y_uniq = tt.extra_ops.Unique()(y)
    Y = tt.zeros(shape=(y.shape[0], y_uniq.shape[0]), dtype='int64')
    Y_hat = tt.zeros_like(Y, dtype='int64')
    rows = tt.arange(y.shape[0], dtype='int64')
    Y = tt.set_subtensor(Y[rows, y], 1)
    Y_hat = tt.set_subtensor(Y_hat[rows, y_hat], 1)
    z = (tt.eq(Y_hat, Y) & tt.eq(Y, 1)).sum(axis=0)
    return theano.function([y, y_hat], outputs=z)


def main():
    y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=np.int64)
    y_hat = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=np.int64)
    y_uniq = np.unique(y)
    result, Y, Y_hat = numpy_ver(y, y_hat)
    print result
    theano_ver1 = compile_theano_ver1()
    print theano_ver1(Y, Y_hat)
    theano_ver2 = compile_theano_ver2()
    print theano_ver2(y, y_hat, y_uniq)
    theano_ver3 = compile_theano_ver3()
    print theano_ver3(y, y_hat)


main()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I should have reported the error that caused me to ask this question in the first place -- one of my first rules of asking questions.  I know I first tried simply using <code>((Y_hat == Y) & (Y == 1)).sum(axis=0)</code> and that the error had something to do with a boolean not having a <code>sum</code> method.  In any case, your solution works.  Thanks again.